# Postgresql default privileges for new schema in multi-tenant Rails application

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, multi-tenant, privileges, apartment-gem

In my Rails 4 multi-tenant application, I create new schemas in Postgresql with the gem [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment).

It works very well but I have a problem with the privileges for new schemas.

In Postgresql, I created a "backup" user to backup my database.

I defined the default privileges with :

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER foo GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER <nom_user_ks-xxx_dbuser> GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO backup;
```

This works for new tables and sequences (as it's explained in Postgresql documentation) in existing schemas but it doesn't work for new schemas.

After googling hours, I can't find a solution.

What is the best way to apply default privileges for new schemas ?

Thanks

Comment: Other way around. That works for new tables and sequences, but doesn't affect existing ones.

Comment: @CraigRinger : I'm sorry to answer only now... I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Is your problem is to change the privileges for existing tables/sequences ? If so, you should use `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;`. `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...` is only for futures tables/sequences.